# PHP Return XML with stream_context_create()

Tags: php, xml, post

I'm using stream_context_create() instead of cURL to make an HTTP post. It works, but file_get_contents() returns a single string of all the data instead of an XML object. How can I modify my code so it returns an XML object and I can access the values individually?

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.domain.com';
$data = array( 'name1' => 'data1', 'name2' => 'data2', 'name3' => 'data3' );

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query( $data )
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create( $options );

$result = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );

var_dump($result); // data1data2data3
?>
```

And the page that returns the XML:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

$xml = '<result><name1>' . $_POST['data1'] . '</name1><name2>' . $_POST['data2'] . '</data2><name3>' . $_POST['data3'] . '</name3></result>';

echo $xml;
?>
```

Comment: Could you provide code which returns XML file on the other side?

Comment: @michail_w Hi, I've updated my question with the code that returns the XML.

Comment: Good code example.  Please add a bit of information of what your environment (OS, development tools).  It might aid in others reproducing/solving your question.

Comment: OS is Linux, distro: CentOS 7 running PHP 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're looking at this var_dump in your browser, and browser tries to render tags `<result>` and `<name..>` as standard HTML.

Please try to run this code, and check the source of your webpage (in Chrome, you can do it by prepending page URL by `view-source:`)

Comment: That was it! Thank you, Michail. I then used simplexml_load_string() to convert the XML string into an XML object so I can easily access the data.